# NPM Sim module and Sim Cordova plugin installed but module still not being detected

Tags: npm-install, ionic5, sim-card

I am trying to develop an app using ionic that picks phone information (sim, imei, etc). I installed the sim module as per https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/ and added it to both my app.module.ts file and home.page.ts files but when I attempt to build or serve I get the error

Cannot find module '@ionic-native/sim/ngx' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 14 import { Sim } from '@ionic-native/sim/ngx';

This error is presented for both the app.module.ts page and home.page.ts page.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';
import { Uid } from '@ionic-native/uid/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

import { Sim } from '@ionic-native/sim/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    Sim,
    UniqueDeviceID,
    Uid,
    AndroidPermissions,  
  { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Home.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';
import { Uid } from '@ionic-native/uid/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

import { Sim } from '@ionic-native/sim/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    
  UniqueDeviceID:string;
  simInformation:any;  

  constructor(
    private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID,
    private uid: Uid,
    private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
    private sim: Sim  
  ) 
  {
        //this.getPermission();
        //this.getUniqueDeviceID();       
  }
  
  
  ionViewWillEnter() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
```

[image]

```
    {
      "name": "ionic-ids-app",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "author": "Ionic Framework",
      "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.32.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.32.1",
        "@ionic-native/sim": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/uid": "^5.32.1",
        "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.32.1",
        "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
        "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
        "cordova-plugin-sim": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-uid": "^1.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-unique-device-id2": "^2.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.4",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "2.0.2",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.0.2",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "2.0.2",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "2.0.2",
        "@angular/cli": "~11.2.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.1",
        "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "eslint": "^7.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "typescript": "~4.0.2"
      },
      "description": "An Ionic project",
      "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
          "cordova-plugin-unique-device-id2": {},
          "cordova-plugin-dreamover-uid": {},
          "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
          "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
          "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
          "cordova-plugin-device": {},
          "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
          "cordova-plugin-sim": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
          "android"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please attach an error screenshot?

Comment: @PareshGami the dependencies have also added dependencies used